# Multiple IDPs in my Simplesamlphp SP Instance

Tags: php, authentication, service-provider, simplesamlphp, idp

i have a web-app with installed SimplesamlPhp. I have multiple different cusomters on this SP all independent of each other. Now i wan't to give every customer the opportunity to add his own IDP without me editing the necessary files everytime.

so i'd like to use the SimplesamlPhp code to convert the customers XML-File generate my own XML-File and add the IDP + authsource, has anyone any excperience with that? The documentation doesn't seem to help. If not possible has anyone another package to recommend?